# Problems using $in in MongoDB with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am facing a strange problem in trying to use $in operator with mongoose and node. Following is the snippet from the code.

```
queryObj = {imei: {$in: queryItems.imei}}
console.log(JSON.stringify(queryObj))

//{"imei":{"$in":[866551038558099,866551038558099, 866551038549072, 866551038536939, 866551038557844]}}
```

The query returns an empty array, whereas if I copy-paste the log in MongoDB Compass, I can see the result set.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const GeofenceReportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    createdOn: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date(),
        required: true
    },
    targetDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    vehicleNo: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: true
    },
    imei: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    numberPlate: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: false
    },
    driverName: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: false
    },
    driverContact: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: false
    },
    startTimeIgnOn: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: false
    },
    endTimeIgnOff: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: false
    },
    idlingTime: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: false
    },
    distance: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true
    },
    averageSpeed: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true
    },
    engineHours: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true
    },
    startOdometer: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true
    },
    endOdometer: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true
    },
    totalFuelConsumption: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true
    },
    totalStops: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true
    },
    geofenceInTime: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: false
    },
    geofenceOutTime: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: false
    },
    distanceInsideGeofence: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: false
    },
    distanceOutsideGeofence: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: false
    },
    performance: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: false
    }
});

let model;
try {
    model = mongoose.model('GeofenceReport');
} catch (error) {
    model = mongoose.model('GeofenceReport', GeofenceReportSchema);
}

module.exports = model;
```

```
function getGeofenceReport(queryItems){
    let queryObj = {$and: [ {targetDate: { $gte: new Date(queryItems.fromTime), $lte: new Date(queryItems.toTime)}},{imei: {$in: queryItems.imei}}]}
    console.log(JSON.stringify(queryObj))
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connectToDatabase().then(() => {
            GeofenceReportSchema.find(queryObj)
                .sort({"targetDate" : 1})
                .then((resp) => {
                    resolve(resp);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    reject(err);
                })
        }).catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

```
Sample data
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "606d82c585ac11242012cb37"
    },
    "createdOn": {
        "$date": "2021-04-07T10:00:37.269Z"
    },
    "targetDate": {
        "$date": "2021-04-06T14:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "vehicleNo": "ABCDE",
    "imei": {
        "$numberLong": "866551038558000"
    },
    "numberPlate": "",
    "driverName": "John Doe",
    "driverContact": 99999999,
    "startTimeIgnOn": "2021-04-06T01:59:44.000Z",
    "endTimeIgnOff": "2021-04-06T11:15:31.000Z",
    "idlingTime": 8344000,
    "distance": 27277.310000000056,
    "averageSpeed": 3.59232320529802,
    "engineHours": 23325000,
    "startOdometer": 658548.82,
    "endOdometer": 685826.13,
    "totalFuelConsumption": 27.277310000000057,
    "totalStops": 8,
    "geofenceInTime": 18043000,
    "geofenceOutTime": 5282000,
    "distanceInsideGeofence": 4421.061251513145,
    "distanceOutsideGeofence": 22856.248748486913,
    "performance": 59.52
}
```

```
Invocation
{
    fromTime : '2021-03-03T18:30:00.000Z',
    toTime: '2021-03-31T18:29:59.000Z',
    imei: 866551038558000
}
```

Note that I have already checked DB connections, have tried with the empty find method and I am able to get data. I have also checked data types. Isn't an issue there. What can be the issue?

Comment: Can you create a small snippet that reproduces the problem, so we can try it, too.

Comment: we can't predict without showing your code, post db connection, schema and your tried query in your question.

Comment: Added code snippet